# Need border to stretch entire menu bar and not just menu items

Tags: css, menu, border

If you check out twoguysplayingzelda.com, you will notice that I have a top and bottom border on my menu that only stretches to the last menu item. I would like to have this border stretch not the entire page, but from the left side of the left window to the right side of the sidebar. If this is confusing, just look at how things are aligned on the left side and right side and hopefully it will make sense. My CSS code is below. Thanks for all your help!

```
div.navigation.section.no-padding.bg-dark { background: #ffffff; }      

.main-menu {        
font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;   
font-size: 1.0em;   
text-align: center; 
}       

.main-menu li { position: relative; }       

.main-menu > li { float: left; }        

.main-menu > li:before {        
content: none;  
display: block; 
position: absolute; 
right: 0;   
top: 50%;   
margin-top: -18px;  
margin-right: -13px;    
}       

.main-menu > li:last-child:before { content: none; }        

.main-menu > li > a {       
display: block; 
padding-top: 12px;  
padding-bottom: 12px;   
padding-left: 12px; 
padding-right: 12px;    
font-size: 1.0em;   
color: #000000; 
text-transform: uppercase;  
letter-spacing: 1px;    
font-weight: 400;
border-bottom: 1px solid #808080; (here is my bottom border)
border-top: 1px solid #808080; (here is my top border)
width: 100%; (I thought this would do the trick but it didn't)
}       

.main-menu > li:first-child > a { margin-left: 0; }     

.main-menu > .has-children > a,     
.main-menu > .page_item_has_children > a { padding-right: 20px; position: 
relative; }     

.main-menu > .has-children > a::after,      
.main-menu > .page_item_has_children > a::after {       
content: "";    
display: none;  
border: 5px solid transparent;  
border-top-color: #999; 
position: absolute; 
z-index: 1001;  
right: 29px;    
top: 50%;   
margin-top: -2px;   
}       

.main-menu li:hover > a { 
cursor: pointer;
background: #01B3D9;  
color: #000000; }       

.main-menu > .has-children:hover > a::after,        
.main-menu > .page_item_has_children:hover > a::after { border-top-color: 
#fff; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The border is on your `.main-menu > li > a` elements, you'll need to remove this.

Then add the border to the containing element, which is your `div.navigation-inner.section-inner`, but you should add another class to add the border styles to that, as you use `navigation-inner section-inner` in ore than one place.

Comment: I'm a little confused on what you mean by div.navigation-inner.section-inner. I don't see inner anywhere in the code, but I am guessing you are referring to the first line. I updated the coding (see below) which did make the border go across the whole page, but when I scroll and the menu sticks to the top, the border goes away. I added that border so it would separate the menu from the content when it stuck to the top. Thanks for help!

    div.navigation.section.no-padding.bg-dark { 
    background: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;
    border-top: 1px solid #808080;
    }